# Can aatmakaaraka be considered while match making

Tags: astrology, horoscopes

I have not heard any astrologer take into account the aatma karaka planet while doing horoscope matching for bride and groom.

But in my experience, aatmakaraka planet's behaviour is very much visible in the life of a person, therefore should be taken into consideration along with Ashtakoot matching